# how to Ignore terminationGracePeriod when host is down?

Tags: kubernetes, lifecycle

I have a Cassandra statefulSet in my Kubernetes cluster with a high terminationGracePeriod to handle data handover currently.

the problem is when a host machine goes down, K8s waits whole terminationGracePeriod in termination phase before rescheduling my pod on another node.

how can i make K8s to ignore terminationGracePeriod when the node is down and reschedule pods immediately?

Answer (score 1):

> the problem is when a host machine goes down, K8s waits whole terminationGracePeriod in termination phase before rescheduling my pod on another node.

I think this is wrong assumption. When a host machine goes down, the node health check is used to detect this. Typically this is e.g. 5 minutes. Only after that, the pods are scheduled to other nodes.

See [Node Condition and pod eviction](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/architecture/nodes/#condition):

> If the status of the Ready condition remains Unknown or False for longer than the pod-eviction-timeout (an argument passed to the kube-controller-manager), then the node controller triggers API-initiated eviction for all Pods assigned to that node. The default eviction timeout duration is **five minutes**.

> how can i make K8s to ignore terminationGracePeriod when the node is down and reschedule pods immediately?

I don't think `terminationGracePeriod` is related to this. A pod gets a `SIGTERM` to shutdown, only if it hasn't successfully been shutdown during the whole *terminationGracePeriod*, it will be killed with `SIGKILL`.

Comment: I get it, but i have a pod stuck in termination status right now, maybe problem is somewhere else.

Comment: yes, the application must properly implement `SIGTERM`.